# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list, item definitely exists

Tags: python

It removes the everything inthe first loop correctly but throws this up when removing the snaps in the second loop, any idea why? I may have been running python 3 and now back to 2.7, could this be my issue? It seems to remove one item from the list and then fails to remove any more.

```
for i in range(0, numOfSnap):
            tempName = baseVv.name + ".ro" + str(i)
            snapVv = baseVv.createSv(name=baseVv.name + ".ro" + str(i), svOptions="-ro -i %s" % x)  
            x += 1                                      
            dlog.info("Creating %s" % tempName)
            baseVv.name + ".rw" + str(i)
            tempName = baseVv.name + ".rw" + str(i)
            rwSnap = snapVv.createSv(name=baseVv.name + ".rw" + str(i), svOptions="-i %s" % x)
            x += 1 
            snapRwVlun = self.cluster.createVlun(vv=rwSnap, host=host)
            dlog.info("Creating %s" % tempName)
            rwSnapList.append(rwSnap)
            vlunList.append(snapRwVlun)
            ## delay random seconds between RO snapshot creation
            time.sleep(random.randint(5,30))

        snapRoList = baseVv.snapSvList

        dlog.info("Stopping IO on VV")
        self.cluster.stopSnapIOOnHosts()

        dlog.info("Starting IO on snaps and VV")           
        self.cluster.startSnapIOOnHosts()
        dlog.info("Sleep 60 seconds for IO to go through")

        time.sleep(60)

        dlog.info("Stopping IO")
        self.cluster.stopSnapIOOnHosts()                       

        time.sleep(60)

        for vluns in vlunList:
            vluns.remove()

        dlog.info("Waiting 60 seconds")    
        time.sleep(60)

        ## randomly pick 1 rw snapshot to delete till removal of all snapshot
        for i in range(0, numOfSnap)[:]:
            snapIndex = random.randint(0, len(rwSnapList)-1)
            dlog.info("remove %s" % rwSnapList[snapIndex].name)
            roSnapshot =  rwSnapList[snapIndex]
            roSnapshot.remove()
            #self.cluster.waitForClusterIntegrated()
            ## remove it from object list
            rwSnapList.remove(roSnapshot)
            time.sleep(random.randint(5,10))

        ## randomly pick 1 ro snapshot to delete till removal of all snapshot
        for i in range(0, numOfSnap)[:]:
            snapIndex = random.randint(0, len(snapRoList)-1)
            dlog.info("remove %s" % snapRoList[snapIndex].name)
            roSnapshot =  snapRoList[snapIndex]
            roSnapshot.remove()
            #self.cluster.waitForClusterIntegrated()
            ## remove it from object list
            snapRoList.remove(roSnapshot)
            time.sleep(random.randint(5,10))
```

Comment: Can you reduce your problem to a simpler (2 or 3 lines) example?

Comment: It looks like a lot of this code is not needed for the error to appear. Could you give us a minimal working example? Or at least tell us which line is going wrong including the stack trace? I'm not going to read all that code and try to guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I was just showing you how the lists were set up, the error is appearing when this line is called 

            snapRoList.remove(roSnapshot)

Comment: but after it had already executed this line once.

Comment: What value does roSnapshot have? Why do you think that particular value breaks it? Also consider what snapRoList contains at that point.

Comment: it's just an object. The script removes volumes from a server. I can see it removed the first .ro volume and then crashing when removing the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of picking a random index from the list of snapshots, *shuffle* the list *once* and pop items from that shuffled list:

```
shuffledSnapList = snapRoList[:]
random.shuffle(shuffledSnapList)

while shuffledSnapList:
    roSnapshot = shuffledSnapList.pop()
```

By using a `while` loop testing against the list you are removing from, you guarantee the loop  will terminate when the list is empty.

Because the list is shuffled, the items are processed in random order.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you go to the trouble of removing them from the list in the first place, you just want to call `.remove()` on all the machines?

```
def removeAll(snapshots, minsleep=5, maxsleep=10):
    random.shuffle(snapshots)
    for snapshot in snapshots:
        dlg.info("remove %s" % snapshot.name)
        snapshot.remove()
        time.sleep(random.randint(minsleep, maxsleep))

removeAll(rwSnapList)
removeAll(roSnapList)
```